# Failure to connect SQL Server and SPARKLYR using spark_read_jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sparklyr

I'm trying to make a connection using library(sparklyr) with SQL Server to extract data from a local db I have on my computer using R Studio. At the end what I want to do is compute with spark doing queries. Please see the syntaxis for reference:

```
library(sparklyr)

#Configuration
config <- spark_config()

# SQL Server JBDC Driver for setting purposes
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-class-path` <- 
  "C:/Program Files/Java/Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.2 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_7.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-7.2.1.jre8.jar"

# Connection to Spark
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

# Want to connect to dbo.Activos
spark_read_jdbc(sc, "person_jdbc",  options = list(
  url = "jdbc:sqlserver://PORT-JBERROCAL/SQLEXPRESS:1433;integratedSecurity=true;",
  user = "root", password = "<password>",
  dbtable = "Activos"))
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Not yet my friend. If you get a workaround or potential solution please share it! =)

Comment: did you get an answer to this?